# Django Signal Registration Throws Incorrect AppnameConfig.name Error

Tags: django, django-settings, django-signals, django-1.11

I am developing a Django app `1.11`, for example  i want email should send after user registration, so I decide to use signals for send email, now instead of putting signal handlers and register code in modal file , I created the `signals.py` in my app folder ,when i trying to import the signals.py on `ready` method in `CommonConfig`, but am getting error like follow

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'common'. Check that 'apps.common.apps.CommonConfig.name' is correct.

My project folder Structure Looks like

`/myproject
   /myproject
   /apps
      /common
   /configs
   /settings
   /static
   /templates`

Installed Apps Looks Like Follow

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
    'rest_framework',
    'apps.common.apps.CommonConfig',]`

and my `apps\common\apps.py` looks like follow

```
`
from django.apps import AppConfig
class CommonConfig(AppConfig):
  name = "common"
```

`

What Mistake i made here, how to register the signal with django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name) attribute is the full Python path, so in your case it should be `"apps.common"`, not `"common"`.

```
class CommonConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "apps.common"
```